# powershell search a certain line in a log file and create an event in event viewer

Tags: powershell-4.0

I have a problem; I would like to automatize something:

I have a *.log file which contains lines of the logged data;
I need to know how to create a script in powershell to search for a certain line, and if that line equals 0, to create an event in the windows event viewer. can somebody please help?
my log looks like this:

data = 1

test = 5

com = 5

connections = 1

When connection = 0 in the *.log file, it should create an event in the event viewer.
If possible as a secondary task I would like to run this script two times a day; at 15:00 and at 00.

Thank you!

tried to find the = 0 with powershell

```
Select-String -Path C:\Users\user\test.log -Pattern '= 0'
IF (Pattern '= 0')
{
Write-EventLog –LogName Application –Source “My Script” –EntryType 
Information –EventID 30000
}
```

error received:

```
Pattern : The term 'Pattern' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or 
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:2 char:5
+ IF (Pattern '= 0')
+     ~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Pattern:String) [], 
CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: I managed to make the first part of the script to work, but now, it does not execute the 2nd part which is writing the event in EventLog:

Comment: PS C:\Windows\system32> $SEL = Select-String -Path C:\Users\user\test.log - 
    Pattern "test =0"
    if ($SEL -ne $null)
    {
    Write-EventLog -LogName Eroare -Source scripts -Message “s-a gasit 0 in log” - 
    EventId 15 -EntryType information
    }
    else
    {
    echo Not Contains String
    }

Comment: the above works, but it throws the following error:Write-EventLog : The source name "scripts" does not exist on computer "localhost".
At line:5 char:5
+     Write-EventLog -LogName Eroare -Source scripts -Message “s-a gasi ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Write-EventLog], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteEventLogCommand

Comment: After PS C:\Windows\system32> New-EventLog -LogName Application -Source “scripts” the following error appeared:   Write-EventLog : The Log name "Eroare" does not exist in the computer "localhost".
At line:5 char:5
+     Write-EventLog -LogName Eroare -Source scripts -Message “s-a gasi ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Write-EventLog], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteEventLogCommand

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this :)  :

Make sure you run Powershell as admin and 
you have rights with the command:

```
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
```

in powershell, and then:

```
$EVENT_SOURCE="verificare.ps1"

if ([System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::SourceExists($EVENT_SOURCE) -eq $false) {
   New-EventLog -LogName Application -Source ‘$EVENT_SOURCE’
   }

 $SEL = Select-String -Path C:\Users\user\test.log -Pattern "test =0"

if ($SEL -ne $null)
{
Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source $EVENT_SOURCE -Message “found xxxxx in 
log” -EventId 30000 -EntryType information
}
else
{
echo Not Contains String
}
```